# Error with XML Response Format with Azure Blob Service API

Tags: xml, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When I am sending a GET request:

```
GET











x-ms-date:Fri, 03 Feb 2017 05:50:10 GMT
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
/xyz/mycontainer
comp:list
delimeter:/
maxresults:1000
prefix:image
restyle:container
```

The request is successful with code 200 and message "OK". But, I am getting error while parsing the response.

> Error: Error while parsing XML: Content is not allowed in prolog.

But when I removed first 3 bytes:

```
while(i!=3){
                System.out.println(in.read());
                i++;
            }
```

It started parsing XML correctly.

When I looked in ASCII table for these codes. I found below characters:

> '╗┐

Why Azure Blob Service Rest API is adding these character at start of XML in response?

My friend said this may be because this particular the response header includes Transfer-Encoding: chunked in header.
But, I don't understand what he is saying and he himself is not sure?

> Code: Simple XML Parsing code.
>
> Response: Starting bits:
>
> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><EnumerationResults
>     > ServiceEndpoint="http://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/"
>     > ContainerName="mycontainer"><Prefix>xyz</Prefix><MaxResults>1000</MaxResults><Blobs><Blob><Name>xyz</Name>
> ```

Comment: Looks like you're not reading the complete response. The XML should have ended with `</Blob></Blobs>`.

Comment: @GauravMantri Gaurav I have not posted the full response. But, thanks I got the answer it was tricky has to go to debugger mode to read full response header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Basically, Azure use different transfer encoding for different response transfer. Usually for big files it uses chunked transfer encoding.

So if I want to transfer data “Arjun_rocks" using chunked transfer encoding. It would be:

```
4\r\n
Arju\r\n
5\r\n
_rock\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

> So, first 3 characters are length of data transferred and then
>   carriage return and then newline character.

The ASCII character which I posted was wrongly interrupted because Azure also compresses the string before sending the data.